# notification custom layout colors and notification bar background color

Tags: android, colors, notifications

I'm interesting in such question. Let one need to create notification with custom layout. Also suppose that this layout has to contain buttons. For example, it is notification for audio player and buttons are play/pause, next and previous. What drawable should be selected for buttons? For to be more exact what color of drawable? How to determine color of system notification bar background?

If this bar has white color, buttons, obviously, shouldn't be white. But colors of notification bar differs on different devices. On FlymeOS it's black, on MIUI it's white, on Nexus it's transparent. So my question is how to determine color of notification bar and depending on that, to select correct drawables, text colors and so on?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Now i hardcoded all colors, i.e. background is black, buttons are white. But it looks not so harmonical as wanted.